# Using dataTable and specify th or td columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery-Visualize by Filament Group, Inc. which produces HTML5 canvas charts driven by HTML table elements.

A requirement of this plugin is, when using a multi-dimensional table, that the first th in the thead row tr needs to be a td.

I display a chart but I have a problem, it shifts:

[image]

Javacript code :

```
function fillDataTable(data) {

if ($("#table_campaigns").css("visibility") == "hidden")
    $("#table_campaigns").css("visibility", "visible");

$('#table_campaigns').dataTable({
    'aaData': data,
    'aoColumns': [
        { "sTitle": "" },
        { "sTitle": "2010" },
        { "sTitle": "2011" },
    { "sTitle": "2012" },
    { "sTitle": "2013" },
    { "sTitle": "2014" }
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
}
```

When I remove ***{ "sTitle": "" }***, I have this : 
[image]

I think my javascript puglin for the chart makes the difference between **td** and **th** tag.
Because in my aspx page, I have that and it works well :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('table').visualize({type: 'line'}).appendTo('body');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <caption>2009 Employee Sales by Department</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th scope="col">2010</th>
                <th scope="col">2011</th>
                <th scope="col">2012</th>
                <th scope="col">2013</th>
                <th scope="col">2014</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                      ...
```

And you can see that I have first **td** tag in **thead** and after **th** tags.

Now I want to do this in my html page :

```
</head>
<body>
<table id="table_campaigns" class="display">
    <caption style="font-size:20px">Statistiek 2 : per productgroep</caption>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I must specify that in my dataTable ***{"sTitle": ""}*** must be a **td**? How to do that? Are there has another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, visualize plugin has a special structure in html must be respected.

You can see the information [here](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/)

I added in my JavaScript :

```
$('tr th:eq(0)').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<td />").append($(this).contents());
});
$('thead th').attr('scope', 'col');
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the right way to do this is using `cellType`:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": "json.txt",
    "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "cellType": "th"
    } ]
} );
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.cellType